# How to make collapsible menus jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm really new at this and I would like to create collapsible menus using jQuery Mobile. I went over to their site and found this resource:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/collapsible/

So, I made a test page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div2014" data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>2014</h3>
            <p>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">Q1</a><br/>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">Q2</a><br/>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">Q3</a><br/>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">Q4</a>
            </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but I can't seem to get it to work. All that gets displayed is this:

[image]

Please help! I'm really new at this, so I'm not sure if I'm doing things right :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the jquery.mobile CSS file as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of jQuery's `slideToggle()` function on click.

See this [**pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGVEqP) and click **2014**, the menu will be displayed and collapsed on clicking it again

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This added the sliding effect that I wanted!